# Calculate cumulative count of a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-frequency

I have created this pandas dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ds = {"col1":[1,2,3,2,2,2,3,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)
```

which looks like this:

```
print(df)

    col1
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      2
4      2
5      2
6      3
7      4
8      1
9      0
10     0
11     0
12     0
13     0
14     1
15     2
16     3
17     5
```

I need to create a new column (`col2`) which contains the cumulative count of the values in `col1`. So, the resulting dataframe would look like this:

[image]

Does anybody know how to do it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is precisely a [`grouby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) function:

```
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1').cumcount().add(1)
```

Output:

```
    col1  col2
0      1     1
1      2     1
2      3     1
3      2     2
4      2     3
5      2     4
6      3     2
7      4     1
8      1     2
9      0     1
10     0     2
11     0     3
12     0     4
13     0     5
14     1     3
15     2     5
16     3     3
17     5     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `cumcount()` after `groupby()`. Add `+1` to start counting from 1 instead of 0:

```
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1').cumcount()+1
```

Returns:

```
    col1  col2
0      1     1
1      2     1
2      3     1
3      2     2
4      2     3
5      2     4
6      3     2
7      4     1
8      1     2
9      0     1
10     0     2
11     0     3
12     0     4
13     0     5
14     1     3
15     2     5
16     3     3
17     5     1
```